# How do I convert image bit depth to 16 bit in UWP?

Tags: c#, image, uwp, bitmap

I'm using FileOpenPicker to allow users to open a **".bmp"**, **".jpg"** or **".PNG"** image.

The imported image then requires pixel conversion before it can work further down the line with a micro-controller using a display that works in **16 bit (RGB-565 format)**.

I'm trying to convert the imported image, but none of the BitmapPixelFormat types are applicable for this.. I can't use System.Drawing either.

I've tried to use the **SoftwareBitmap** class to convert imported images to the Rbga8 format, but that's as close as I got.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                if (bitmapImage.PixelWidth <= 140 && bitmapImage.PixelHeight <= 190)
                {
                    // Create the decoder from the stream
                    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
                    // Get the SoftwareBitmap representation of the file
                    SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
                    SoftwareBitmap outputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);

                    SplashImage = bitmapImage;
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplaySplashImageErrorDialog();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Windows Imaging Component (WIC) can do these kinds of conversions. For using it from C# in a UWP, take a look at [Win2D](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D).

Comment: Hi, Do you want to convert Rgb888 to Rgb565 or vice versa? I recommend that you convert the stream to a byte array and adjust the corresponding RGB digits based on the two encoding methods.

Comment: Hi Richard, I'd be looking to convert a Rgb888 to Rgb565 just one-way. I thought about bit shifting the 3 bytes to 2 bytes, but I thought there might be some function out there to do this in UWP. Nevermind I'll come up with something and post it here. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, bizarre. There is no direct way to convert Rgb888 to Rgb565 in the `.net standard`. You can write your own methods or use third-party libraries.